# How to eliminate quadruple-clicks in UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp, click, focus

I am developing a UWP prototype app. On one of the pages, there is an AdaptiveGridView that shows a number of Buttons as Tiles. It takes 4 clicks before the click event of one of the buttons fires. Now I am trying to find out why and how to eliminate the 3 extra clicks.
This is what I tried so far:

a) I selected "Track Focused Element" from the black controls displayed on top of the app windows during debug sessions. Nothing shows as Focused the first three clicks

b) I added a GotFocus Event at the top Grid in the page to catch the bubbled up event and printed the OriginalSource of the Event in a Debug.WriteLine. For the first three clicks, nothing is displayed in the output window.

c) I set the Focus on the first button in the AdaptiveGrid with _button.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard)

So far nothing has helped. I still have to click 4 times to fire the click event. I tried to reproduce it in a small app to demonstrate the problem. Unfortunately it does not show the same problem and fires the clicks the first time. The real app I cannot post here because it would not work without a database and it's soap services apart from being too big.

How else could I diagnose and remedy the problem of the 4 clicks?

Comment: This seems rather like the UI thread is blocked. If you wait for a couple of seconds, does this still happen? When hovering over the button, does the button react by changing color?

Comment: It is not time dependent. I could wait half an hour and still would have to do 4 clicks. No the button does not change color until it has been clicked 3 times.

Comment: That is extremely weird :-O. As if there is an invisible layer above... It would be great if you somehow could create a repo of the problem, even though I understand it is complex, but I am afraid we won't be able to help without it...

Comment: 1 tip I can give u is to use item selection instead, or try using tapped even instead of click event.

Comment: @touseefbsb: I am not exactly sure how you would implement item selection based navigation in a tile grid, but a button is not selected until it was clicked 3 times, so that would not help either. I tried the three methods of invoking a method upon a button click: 1) Click Event, 2) Command, 3) Tapped Event. They are invoked in this sequence 1,2,3, but only after the 4th click in my case.

Comment: use the SelectionChanged event and then navigate according to the selecteditem or selectedindex.